# couchapp+evently: _init/data.js and $$(this)

Tags: couchapp, evently

I'm reading the couchapp tutorial http://couchapp.org/page/evently-do-it-yourself-ii-state and am confused on two points (I don't like being told answers without knowing why they are what they are):

> ```
> $ cat data.js
> function(e) {
>   $$(this).toppings = [];
> }
> ```

- What's the "e" parameter in data.js?
- What exactly does the $$(this) function return, and how do I find out more about it? Is it solely user-definable state, or are there methods or special state parameters that I need to know about?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more about `$$()` in [this post from wycats](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/04/20/evented-programming-with-jquery/), as reported [in the sources](https://github.com/couchapp/evently/blob/master/lib/jquery.evently.js#L6).

I don't use Evently any more, so I don't remember what the `e` parameter is. However you can easily check it using Firebug.